# How can I size a UICollectionViewCell based on the content of a UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm dynamically adding `UICollectionViewCell`s to a `UICollectionView` using the delegate method `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. The `UICollectionViewCell` that is created every time that method runs contains a `UIWebView` with content that is of varying size. I cannot set the size of the `UICollectionViewCell` when creating it programmatically. Instead, I have to implement a method called `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.

Unfortunately, this size-determining method seems to be called *before* the method that actually creates the cells. At this time, I cannot reference the size of the `UIWebView` to help find a good size for the cells. All I have is the actual content of the `UIWebView`, but I have no idea how to use this to find size, since the content includes styled HTML and images.

I tried to create `UIWebViews` in memory and to get sizes from them, but I always got 0 for dimensions. I'm somewhat relieved this didn't work because it seems like an ugly hack to me.

Is there something else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is one of the things I tried. Unfortunately, when I do this, the frame's size is zero for both axes. I imagine this is because the `UIWebView` is not created yet at this point, so getting it's frame isn't yet possible.

Comment: @MacMark In my case UIWebView is not scaling up to it's content size and it overlaps other views in UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer works not with UICollectionView but with UITableView. This worked for me in a UICollectionViewController:

```
 NSString *webViewHeight =  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"idOfMainElementInHtml\").offsetHeight;"];
```

Use this in

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Remember the values in a NSMutableDictionary which maps NSIndexPath objects to height values. Compare the previous value with the new value every time in this method and then let the Layout object use this dictionary to calculate a new layout.

Have fun :-)

Comment: Thanks again. I also tried this, and I also got zero for the height.

Comment: In that case the HTML element is not found by the given ID. Enable developer mode in Safari (desktop) and connect with the developer menu to the web view in your iOS simulator. Try to run the JavaScript with getElementById in the Web Inspector line at the bottom until you get the expected result. Also check the HTML live with Web Inspector. Compare session 600 from WWDC 2012 named "Debugging UIWebViews and Websites on iOS".

Comment: Depending on your HTML you can also try [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"];